# How to level this plane to z=0

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, linear-algebra

**Idea**
Trying to plot a plane based on two vectors and centered at the origin of the vectors

**Issue**
The plane isn't located at z=0 (since these vectors are in R2, it is expected to do so.)

**Details**
The vectors are taken from a matrix entered and stored in "valor". To run the cross function is needed vectors of size 3, but valor is of size 2, so it is created another matrix called valor1 to adjust this.

**Code**

```
   figure(1);
   valor1 =[ valor(1,1) valor(1,2) 0; valor(2,1) valor(2,2) 0;0 0 0]; #adjusted matrix to run cross
    v1 = valor1(:,1);
    v1 = v1 / norm(v1) ; #normalized vectors
    v2 = valor1(:,2);
    v2 = v2 / norm(v2 ) ;
    p = 10*(rand(3,1) - 0.5);  #points of the plane
    v3 = cross(v1,v2);   #cross product
    [ x , y ] = meshgrid( p(1)+(-5:5) , p(2)+(-5:5) ); #the limits of the plane
    z = p(3) - (v3(1)*(x-p(1)) + v3(2)*(y-p(2)))/v3(3); #plane equation
    surf(x,y,z) #graph it all
    hold all
    z = zeros(size(valor, 1), 1); 
    quiver3(z, z, z, valor(:, 1), valor(:, 2), z, 0); #plot the vectors entered
    hold off
    axis equal
```

**Example obtained**
[image]

**What was expected**
The plane must have their origin at the same origin of the vectors

[image]

Comment: I am no valor expert, but shouldn't you compensate for the outcome of the cross product, the absolute value of v3? I.e.; subtract the component somewhere?

Comment: @Stefan, I understand this is not necessary, since cross is only to align the direction of the plane (that is expected to be in z=0, due the vectors are in R2),  and z is defined in the plane equation.

Comment: Hmm... I need to dig up some of my Linear Algebra... anyhow, yet another, perhaps annoying question, but; your vectors are 2d; what do you want to do with the outcome? I dont think z is well defined in your case and could be arbitrary. This is besides the plotting of the graph obviously, but that would be easily manipulated

Comment: Because v3 is vertical, `v3(1) = v3(2) = 0`. The plane equation becomes `z = p(3) - (0*(x-p(1))+0*(y-p(2)))/v3(3)`. The term in the parenthesis after `p(3)` is zero. Therefore you end with `z = p(3) ~= 0`. As @Stephan points out, the role of `z` is not well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `p` is defining a point on the plane. However, because `p` is being generated randomly using `p = 10*(rand(3,1) - 0.5);`, generally speaking the z-coordinate of that point is not 0 (as @JAC pointed out).

It's not clear to me why you are randomly generating (and then subtracting 0.5) a point rather than simply setting `p = [0 0 0]`, but assuming you have a good reason to do that, simply force p(3) to be 0 as in the adapted code below.

```
figure(1);
valor1 =[ valor(1,1) valor(1,2) 0; valor(2,1) valor(2,2) 0;0 0 0]; %adjusted matrix to run cross
v1 = valor1(:,1);
v1 = v1 / norm(v1) ; %normalized vectors
v2 = valor1(:,2);
v2 = v2 / norm(v2 ) ;
p = [10*(rand(2,1) - 0.5); 0];  %point on the plane with z=0
v3 = cross(v1,v2);   %cross product
[ x , y ] = meshgrid( p(1)+(-5:5) , p(2)+(-5:5) ); %the limits of the plane
z = p(3) - (v3(1)*(x-p(1)) + v3(2)*(y-p(2)))/v3(3); %plane equation
surf(x,y,z) %graph it all
hold all
z = zeros(size(valor, 1), 1); 
quiver3(z, z, z, valor(:, 1), valor(:, 2), z, 0); %plot the vectors entered
hold off
axis equal
```

Comment: JMikes: This method still does not what I intend to do, could you suggest me another way to do so? Thanks

Comment: @riccs_0x The expected behaviour you defined in your question was that "the plane must have their origin at the same origin of the vectors". The above code accomplishes that behaviour. If the above answer doesn't solve your problem, please clarify, being as specific as possible, what it is you "intend to do" and in what way the current response fails to do that.